# Adding a password authenticated user to a peer authenticated postgres setup not working

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add a read-only user to a postgres setup on a remote server with default peer authentication, that uses a **password** as an authentication method.

I create my user like this:

```
CREATE USER my_user WITH PASSWORD 'some_pass';
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO my_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO my_user;
```

and I have added a rule to the pg_hba.conf file, stating that this particular user should be able to access the database using a password.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   my_db           my_user                                 password <- my new line
local   all             all                                     peer
```

And then I start `psql` from the command line like this:

```
psql -d my_db -U my_user -W
```

and provide 'some_pass' when prompted. This works fine locally, but on the server I get this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "my_user"
```

Do I need to restart postgresql so that the changes in pg_hba.conf will take effect, or is there something else missing?  I am reluctant to restart postgresql since it is being used on a production environment.

**EDIT:** I mention that the server is remote, but I log into it first using ssh before accessing the database, meaning that the connection to the database is in fact local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user connects from a remote client host, so the authentication type, must be `host`, not `local` which is used for local connections using named pipes.

The "password" authenticaion method should not be used either, as it sends the password in cleartext. Use `md5` instead (or if your Postgres server is configured for it, `scram-sha-256`)

To allow remote connections you also need to put in an IP address. If you know the IP address you could add that. Using `0.0.0.0/0` would allow a connection from *any* IP address.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host   my_db           my_user          0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

If the client computer is located in the same network as the Postgres server, `samenet` would be a safer choice than `0.0.0.0/0`

To apply changes to `pg_hba.conf` you need to reload the configuration. A restart is not needed. Reloading can e.g. be done through `select pg_reload_conf();` while being connected as the superuser.

Comment: I see now that I probably shouldn't have mentioned that the server is remote, since I first log into the server using ssh, so the connection to the database is technically local (will update the question). But good advice about the `scram-sha-256`, I will definitely rather use that then a password, and the `select pg_reload_conf()` is the answer I needed. Thanks!

Comment: If you use `scram-sha-256` you must first change the Postgres server to also store passwords with `scram-sha-256`. If you change that on the server, then you must set the password again for that user, in order to overwrite the current md5 hash.